# No internet access after assigning Static IP address on android for a Win 10 hotspot

Tags: windows-10, ip, android, ip-address, static-ip

Setting static IP Address on android device, results in its WiFi connection not working (no internet). If its DHCP on the android device, WiFi (internet) works. I am using inbuilt hotspot of windows 10.[Network adapter properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAbPG.png)

Comment: What IP address are you applying to the Android?

Comment: tried many... 192.168.137.xx to 192.168.1.xx

Comment: Make sure you have the correct gateway and DNS i.e `192.168.137.1` and 8.8.8.8 respectively

Answer (score 0):

When using the mobile hotspot, the checkbox on the main network adapter> Sharing tab should be unchecked otherwise the mobile hotspot will never work. This box should only be enabled if you use the Hostednetwork function.

Change back to DHCP, after your phone is connected, still on the phone open the network info of the connection (gear menu, network and internet, the hotspot name, then long press the hotspot name, on the window that opens copy down all the settings (IP, Subnet, Gateway and dns)...put those settings into the static setting on the connection on Android...don't change anything on the windows hotspot connectoid except maybe network name and password AND just to be sure ANY band (instead of 2g or 5g).

give it a shot see if it works.

Comment: sorry if i wasn't able to understand correctly but if you are saying to view network details of hotspot on android while i am connected to it on DHCP, then it only shows network name, signal strength, security, proxy settings (NONE) and IP settings (DHCP)